# how disable E_DEPRECATED in php for joomdle configuration

Tags: joomla, php, error-reporting

i use joomdle for integrating moodle and joomla but i face this message

> E_DEPRECATED errors are enabled in your PHP configuration

and say me disable this setting .
i change php.ini to :

> error_reporting = ~E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED

but joomla say :

> E_DEPRECATED errors are enabled in your PHP configuration

are there way for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla's configuration allows one to set a custom error reporting level, which overrides the one set in php.ini

Did you try ?

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I think this will works.
Good luck.